# Is there a way of having a variable number of typenames in a template function, like parameter pack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, constexpr

I'm on a microcontroller, so in order to avoid the new operator, I reserve some memory to be used in a placement new operator call. I'd like to determine the minimum size of that memory by supplying a number of types to a constexpr function that will return the largest type in the list.

```
struct A
{
   int foo;
   int bar[24];
};
struct B
{
   int foo;
   int bar[126];
};


uint8_t objectMem[max_sizeof<A, B>());
```

Is there such a thing as a "parameter pack" for typenames? I'd like to be able to append any number of types as template arguments.

Comment: `std::max({sizeof(A), sizeof(B)})` Recall that `std::max` is `constexpr` since C++14

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you want `max_sizeof<A, B, C, ..., X, Y, Z>()` to work?

Comment: but.. why not an `union` or `std::variant`? How do you intent to use `objectMem`? Have you properly handled alignment requirements?

Comment: Keep in mind the alignment should be considered as well, not just the size.

Comment: Note that your solution is illegal due to misalignment. `objectMem` can be anywhere in the memory, while objects of `A` and `B` need to be aligned to 4-byte boundaries (generally, `alignof(int)`-byte). Use `std::aligned_union`, it will guarantee correct alignment for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr size_t max_sizeof() {
  return sizeof(std::aligned_union<0, Ts...>::type);
}
```

Comment: If we're going with `aligned_union`, it's worth noting that `std::aligned_union_t<0, A, B>` is already a suitable type for  `objectMem`, so using it only for the size here is a bit roundabout.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I came to the same conclusion. Modern C++ sure has nice things for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use variadic templates:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Your required size can be implemented as a variable template:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template

Finally, you may consider using `std::variant` API:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant